# How can I use a variable saved from a mysql connection with NodeJS to an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to scrape a website with Puppeteer. I want to select the date of the last post inserted in my database and compare it to the dates taken by the scrape so I can see if the post is already in the database (using the date as the reference to see if it has been modified).

Here is my code:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'db_webcrawler_coches'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected!');
});

let lastpublishedDate;
let idCoches;
connection.query("SELECT id_coches, publish_date FROM coches ORDER BY publish_date DESC limit 1", function (err, row) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lastPublishedDate =  row[0].publish_date;
    idCoches = row[0].id_cochesNet;
    console.log("Published in", lastPublishedDate);
    console.log("Id Coches", idCoches);
});

const run = async () => {
    try {
        const options = {
            headless: false,
        };

        ...

            const news = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const idsList =  [...document.querySelectorAll('div.mt-SerpList-item')].map(elem => elem.getAttribute("id")).filter(elem => elem.includes("#"))
                const datePost = [...document.querySelectorAll('span.mt-CardAd-date')].map(elem => elem.innerText);

                    for(let i = 0; i < titlesCar.length; i++){
                        const finalDate = parsedDates[i];
                        if (finalDate > lastPublishedDate || idCoches !== idsList[i]){
                            console.log("Not repeated");

                            const carsList[i] = [
                                idsList[i],
                                parsedDates[i]
                            ]
                        } else {
                            console.log("Repeated")
                        }
                    }
                return carsList;

            });

            ...


  } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Browser Closed");
    }
  };

run();
```

As you can see I want to see if the date is the same or not as well as the id taken from the query. However, it appears an error that says **Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: variable "lastPublishedDate" is not defined** and I imagine that it will be the same with "idCoches".  I wrote some console.logs to see when it crashes and it seems that it happens when reaches the **function "news"**.
I'm not sure if it is because it is the scope or because of the function. What do you think I should do to make it work?

Could it be the scope?
Thank you!

**EDIT: SOLVED!**
I post it in the case that anyone faces a similar issue.
Indeed it was the scope, it is a problem related to Puppeteer. It seems that the function with page.evaluate() is unable to take any variable outside of it. To change it you need to add the page.evaluate in the following way:
**await page.evaluate((variable_1, variable_2) => { /* ... */ }, variable_1, variable_2);**

Comment: why not moving your `connection.query` inside `run` function, and using its result as promise to run the rest of your `run` function?

Comment: you can read about scopes and where the Let variables are defined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback to your Query probably does has not returned yet when the async function is run, so whatever your trying to reference is not defined.
I'm not sure if your mysql client supports promises, but if it does you could do something like this:

```
const run = async () => {
   const row = await connection.query("SELECT id_coches, publish_date FROM coches ORDER BY publish_date DESC limit 1")
   lastPublishedDate =  row[0].publish_date;
   idCoches = row[0].id_cochesNet;

   ...

}
```

If that does not work you could also run everything inside the callback of the query. Hope that helps.